# how to customize top menu in magento using rwd template?

Tags: frontend

I am using rwd template in magento 1.9.1
I wants to add my own customize menu in top menu bar so it would be drop down in mobile view.so how can i add new menu in top menu bar?

Is there any changes need in xml files or php file?

Comment: Add link in top menu in magento 1 Refer a link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/249589/72237

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rwd\default\template\page\html\topmenu.phtml
```

This template is all about top menu.you can remove all code in it. Then
You can put your all menu in this.

Warning :- It is fast way create your menu but not proper way.

Comment: then what is proper way?how to add category in menu?

Comment: from backend. login to your admin goto catalog in top menu select manage  category and then you can find add category.

Comment: i did it.but not showing in front end

Comment: Then you miss something or doing something wrong.

Comment: Just Select Parent then click to add sub category.You can see a form give name to that category set  " Is Active " To Yes ,  set " Include in Navigation Menu " to yes Press save.Now you show new sub category under that parent category that you selected.

Comment: how to change color of account icon.currently its gray

Comment: how to  link login page with cms page that i have craeted?

Comment: 1. Account icon cannot be set from backend so you have do this with css. 2. I cannot under stand your second question properly Means you really want to change login link url ?